# Error when saving data to MongoDB database

Tags: python, database, mongodb, discord.py, pymongo

I want to make a role assignment using the support approval on the discord server, in general, a complex system.. To do this, I need to save the message id and the id of the message author who needs to be assigned a role, all the code is working, an error in the line of code associated with the database.

event code

```py
cluster = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://corry:pa4-pD6-3Dj-AdT@cluster0.gi8x6.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
db = cluster.RolesData
roles = db.RolesCollection

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()
    request = ['роль', 'хочу роль', 'дайте роль', 'нужна роль']

    if msg in request:
        for i in orgs:
            if not message.author.display_name.split(' ')[0].replace('[', '') in orgs:
                await message.channel.send(f'`[ROLES]`: {message.author.mention}, тег организации не найден!')
                break

            if i == message.author.display_name.split(' ')[0].replace('[', ''):
                guild = bot.get_guild(831511376425123882)
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=orgs[i])

                await message.channel.send(f'`[ROLES]`: {message.author.mention}, ваш запрос на получение роли был отправлен саппортам!')

                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title='Запрос на получение роли!',
                    description='✅ - выдать роль\n❌ - отклонить запрос\n️ - изменить никнейм\n - запросить статистику',
                    color=0x000000
                )
                embed.add_field(name=f'Пользователь:', value=f'{message.author.mention}', inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name=f'Никнейм:', value=f'{message.author.display_name}', inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name=f'Роль для выдачи:', value=f'{role.mention}', inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://psv4.userapi.com/c537232/u356224017/docs/d1/416eb92aec38/rodina.png?extra=2E9CwKZ0PIjnG8aaNkwehlHwjxlycBfGx-4p20ABm3mPI4jNpdV1OXaUUA9zGA4Q04VM21UezrXsjtqC411Xbh-Ro7rW1L4OGgNxpcQv3lvfOYCb-Irn-_-51AaQa2fpNDZhHm80dvZm1HlR1ZWoDigw')
                embed.set_image(url=message.author.avatar_url)

                msgemb = await bot.get_channel(851413212485779466).send(embed=embed)

                await msgemb.add_reaction('✅')
                await msgemb.add_reaction('❌')
                await msgemb.add_reaction('️')
                await msgemb.add_reaction('')

                roles_post = {
                    'm_id':msg_db.id,
                    'user':msg_db.author
                }

                if roles.count_documents({'m_id':message.id}) == 0:
                    roles.insert_one(roles_post)
                else:
                    await message.channel.send(f'`[ROLES]`: {message.author.mention}, вы уже отправили запрос на получение роли!')
```

error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 89, in _resolve_uri
    results = _resolve(
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 43, in _resolve
    return resolver.resolve(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 1305, in resolve
    return get_default_resolver().resolve(qname, rdtype, rdclass, tcp, source,
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 1176, in resolve
    timeout = self._compute_timeout(start, lifetime)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 997, in _compute_timeout
    raise Timeout(timeout=duration)
dns.exception.Timeout: The DNS operation timed out after 21.201510190963745 seconds

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\Desktop\rodina\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    cluster = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://corry:pa4-pD6-3Dj-AdT@cluster0.gi8x6.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 704, in __init__
    res = uri_parser.parse_uri(
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\uri_parser.py", line 542, in parse_uri
    nodes = dns_resolver.get_hosts()
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 121, in get_hosts
    _, nodes = self._get_srv_response_and_hosts(True)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 101, in _get_srv_response_and_hosts
    results = self._resolve_uri(encapsulate_errors)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 97, in _resolve_uri
    raise ConfigurationError(str(exc))
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The DNS operation timed out after 21.201510190963745 seconds
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Comment: There should have been another line that said exactly what the error was.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] (emphasis on *minimal*)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this bit `self._raise_connection_failure(error)` in your error message, I believe the issue lies within the fact that you're not successfully connecting to your db in the first place.

Comment: Except that the `roles.count_documents` in the previous line apparently succeeded.

Comment: I also realized that I was connecting the database incorrectly, redid it and got a new error. I edited the message